# Akkusativ Markieren für Lokale Präpositionen

Tags: accusative

Ich habe eine Frage. Ich habe zwei Sätze geformt:

1. *Stell die Tasse **in die Küche** **auf den Schrank**.*
2. *Stell die Tasse **in der Küche** **auf den Schrank**.*

Soll ich die Lokale Präpositionen zweimal als Akkusativ markieren hier: einmal mit **in die Küche** und einmal mit **auf den Schrank**? Oder nein? Sind die Sätze richtig oder falsch?

Vielendank!

Comment: Im Deutschen gibt es keinen Grund, einen Kasus in einer Verbphrase nur einmal zu verwenden (wie z.B. im Englischen!). Wenn zwei Präpositionen den Akkusativ regieren, steht er auch zweimal. (Es gibt sogar manche Verben, die zweimal Akkusativ fordern.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *»In die Küche«* (Akkusativ = Richtung) bedeutet, dass die Tasse vorher außerhalb der Küche war und von außen in die Küche hinein transportiert wird.
- *»In der Küche«* (Dativ = an einem Ort) bedeutet, dass man sich mitsamt der Tasse bereits in der Küche befindet und - ohne die Küche zu verlassen - dort, in diesem Raum etwas mit der Tasse macht.
- *»Auf den Schrank«* (Akkusativ = Richtung) bedeutet, dass die Tasse vorher irgendwo anders war, und an die obere Außenfläche des Schrankes bewegt wird.
- *»Auf dem Schrank«* (Dativ = an einem Ort) würde bedeutet, dass sich die Tasse die ganze Zeit oben auf der oberen Außenfläche des Schrankes befindet, und weder dorthin noch von dort weg bewegt wird.

Der erste Satz ist daher zwar richtig, aber irgendwie doppelt gemoppelt, weil zwei Richtungsangaben enthalten sind.

> Stelle die Tasse bitte in die Küche auf den Schrank. =
> Stelle die Tasse bitte in die Küche und stelle sie dabei bitte auf den Schrank.

Schöner wäre diese Variante:

> Stelle die Tasse bitte **auf den Schrank in der Küche.**

Denn hier ist die Nominalgruppe *»in der Küche«* eine Beschreibung des Ortes, an dem sich der Schrank befindet. *»In der Küche«* hat in diesem Satz keinen direkten Bezug mehr zur Tasse, sondern bezieht sich auf den Schrank.

Der Satz bedeutet also:

> Stelle die Tasse bitte auf den Schrank. Der Schrank ist in der Küche.

In umgekehrter Reihenfolge bedeuten die Teile etwas anderes:

> Stelle die Tasse bitte **in der Küche auf den Schrank.**

Hier bezieht sich *»in der Küche«* auf den Ort an dem die Bewegung stattfinden soll. Also:

> Stelle die Tasse bitte auf den Schrank. Mach das bitte in der Küche.

Answer (score 4):

Beides ist möglich und vollkommen korrekt. Die zweite Variante kann man immer benutzen.

Die erste Variante mit "in die Küche" benutzt man nur, wenn die Tasse vorher in einem anderen Raum war. Diese Variante betont mehr, dass das Ziel die Küche ist.

Die Variante "in der Küche auf den Schrank" würde man eher benutzen, wenn "auf den Schrank" die wichtigere Information ist, das "in der Küche" ist dann eher eine Zusatzinformation.

Das Beispiel ist aber aus dem einfachen mündlichen Gebrauch in der Alltagssprache. Man kann hier zwar die Satzstruktur und deren Bedeutung analysieren, und bekommt dann auch ein Ergebnis, aber in der Praxis kommen alle Varianten vor, ohne dass sich der Sprecher da tiefe Gedanken macht. Man wird "in die Küche" nicht sagen, wenn die Tasse schon in der Küche ist, aber ansonsten würde ich da nicht allzusehr Bedeutungsnuancen abwägen.

Comment: Ich würde in der ersten Variante immer ein Komma setzen: "Stell die Tasse in die Küche, auf den Schrank." Üblicherweise ist "auf den Schrank" hier eine nachträgliche Präzisierung.

Comment: Würde ich normalerweise nicht machen, aber klar, man kann definitv ein Komma setzen, wenn man es so versteht.